# Pre-render 3D object from multiple angles, save as PNG

Tags: 3d

I'm looking for a tool or script that takes a 3D object (any format) and makes multiple renders of it *automatically* (using a raytracer or other high-quality offline renderer). It would then save the output as a series of PNG files.

Example: let me render a car from angles 0,90,180,270 and save the images to car0.png, car1.png, car2.png and car3.png with a single command.

Is there such a tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [POVRay](http://www.povray.org)? It's free and can be automated.

http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.0/792/

See this page for info on generating several different images:

http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.0/109/

Comment: Looking at that page, is it possible to set the camera angle as a parameter or would I have to generate a separate scene file for each?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but i guess the camera location is in the pov file, so you'd need to create as many files are there are camera locations.

Comment: You can use the clock variable to automate it http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.0/109/

Comment: Aha! The clock variable looks like it's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Blender](http://blender.org/), it's an OSS 3D modeling and animation suite [scriptable with Python](http://www.blender.org/education-help/python/)

Comment: There is a nice tutorial for Blender on [TigSource](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=4307.0)

Answer (score 0):

3D Studio Max ,

Maya

Both are quite expensive though

Comment: You forgot to mention that both can be scripted, using MaxScript for 3ds max, MEL or Python for Maya. I've written scripts to do this exact task.

Comment: Thanx for the comment, I knew scripting was possible to some degree, but not that it would be possible to do exactly this